# Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(NSData!, NSError!) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(NSData!, NSError!) -> Void'

Tags: swift, swift2, nsjsonserialization

I was trying to convert from Swift 1 to 2 in the line `if let jsonData Array = try NSJSONSerialization...` because it was originally giving me an error from the "extra argument 'error' in call" so I added the "try" before NSJSONSerialization but now it's saying "Invalid conversion from throwing function of type `'(NSData!, NSError!) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(NSData!, NSError!) -> Void'`.  I think the error isn't handled properly but I don't know how to do that. Here's the code

```
httpHelper.sendRequest(httpRequest, completion: {(data:NSData!, error:NSError!) in
        if error != nil {
            let errorMessage = self.httpHelper.getErrorMessage(error)
            let errorAlert = UIAlertView(title:"Error", message:errorMessage as String, delegate:nil, cancelButtonTitle:"Ok")
            errorAlert.show()

            return
        }

        var error: NSError?

        // let jsonDataDict = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: &error) as! NSDictionary
        //  let jsonDataDict = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as! NSDictionary

        if let jsonDataArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as? NSArray! {
            //load collection view with selfies
            if jsonDataArray != nil {
                for imageDataDict in jsonDataArray {
                    var selfieImgObj = SelfieImage()

                    selfieImgObj.imageTitle = imageDataDict.valueForKey("title") as! String
                    selfieImgObj.imageId = imageDataDict.valueForKey("random_id") as! String
                    selfieImgObj.imageThumbnailURL = imageDataDict.valueForKey("image_url") as! String

                    self.dataArray.append(selfieImgObj)
                }

                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
        }
      })
    }
```

Comment: For some reason it's not showing the first few lines as code. Before "return" is                                                                      httpHelper.sendRequest(httpRequest, completion: {(data:NSData!, error:NSError!) in
        if error != nil {
            let errorMessage = self.httpHelper.getErrorMessage(error)
            let errorAlert = UIAlertView(title:"Error", message:errorMessage as String, delegate:nil, cancelButtonTitle:"Ok")
            errorAlert.show()

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be wrapping any functions that call `throws` in a `do-try-catch` loop.  Secondly, safely unwrap the `jsonArray` as a Swift Array rather than trying to force cast it to an `NSArray`:

```
do {
    if let jsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(NSData(), options: .AllowFragments) as? [AnyObject] {
        // unarchived data is an array
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```